# Swift Firebase persistence

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, runtime-error

I'm trying to enable Firebase Persistence but my code keeps crashing with:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type `NSException`

I have tried the line of code under my viewDidLoad as well as under DataService but I still get the same crash. what do I need to do to resolve this problem I'm facing

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeTeamSelectionVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var club: Clubs!
    var player = [Players]()
    var playerFirstName = String()
    var playerLastName = String()
    var playerSelected: Bool = false


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true //Correct use of????

        CLUB_KEY = ""
        CLUB_KEY = club.clubKey

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self


        DataService.ds.REF_PLAYERS.queryOrdered(byChild: "clubKey").queryEqual(toValue: club.clubKey).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            print("PLAYERS_COUNT: \(snapshot.childrenCount)")
            print("PLAYERS_SNAPSHOT: \(snapshot)")

            self.player = []
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                for snap in snapshots {
                    if let playerDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key

                        let players = Players(playerKey: key, dictionary: playerDict)
                        self.player.append(players)

                    }
                }
            }
            //            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print("CHET: local error")
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return player.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let players = player[indexPath.row]
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTeamPlayersCell") as? HomeTeamPlayersCell {
            cell.configureCell(players)
            return cell
        } else {
            return HomeTeamPlayersCell()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let players: Players!
        players = player[indexPath.row]

        print (players.playerKey)
        print (players.playerFirstName)
        print (players.playerLastName)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Firebase documentation for `persistenceEnabled` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase?hl=pt-br#persistenceenabled):

> Note that this property must be set before creating your first Database reference and only needs to be called once per application.

As such, the standard practice is to set it *once* in your `AppDelegate` class. For instance:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    ...
    return true
```

}

Comment: I added it to my AppDelegate which corrected the issue